# Google Dataflow with "Workflow failed"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm working on simple beam dataflow in JAVA on google cloud platform. I've tested locally and the pipeline is running well.

When i deploy on dataflow, i got this looping error :

```
{
  insertId: "10mkpdlb7i"
  labels: {4}
  logName: "projects/myproject/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"
  receiveTimestamp: "2022-11-14T09:09:08.216192037Z"
  resource: {
    labels: {
      job_id: "2022-11-14_01_20_11-8382597753945077942"
      job_name: "production-validation-pipeline"
      project_id: "3456543"
      region: "europe-west1"
      step_id: ""
    }
    type: "dataflow_step"
  }
  severity: "ERROR"
  textPayload: "Workflow failed."
  timestamp: "2022-11-14T09:09:07.793137682Z"
}
```

My dataflow :

- read from kafka
- filter message -> keep some of them based on value in the message
- convert to pubsub message
- push to pubsub

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you also check the job logs, workers logs and diagnostics tab from `Dataflow` GUI if there are more details on the current error ?

Comment: I found this log as 
Internal Issue (cb8641f3e58ae6e4): 63963027:24112 :
{
insertId: "1aw44twb80"
labels: {4}
logName: "projects/myproject/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-11-14T14:43:09.109573279Z"
resource: {
labels: {
job_id: "2022-11-14_06_36_49-2382052343911558560"
job_name: "production-validation-pipeline"
project_id: "855947445485"
region: "europe-west1"
step_id: ""
}
type: "dataflow_step"
}
severity: "WARNING"
textPayload: "Internal Issue (cb8641f3e58ae6e4): 63963027:24112"
timestamp: "2022-11-14T14:43:08.459520930Z"
}

Comment: Did you got any luck with this issue - I am facing the same issue "Internal Issue (c27629d85683fe1b): 63963027:24112"